# What are the transistors for in this half-bridge non-isolated supply?

Tags: transistors, ac

This circuit is to drive MOSFETs connected to mains using optocouplers that are not in the schematic.

I don't understand the transistor usage.  What are they here for?

There is a version with only one resistor and only one transistor.  I believe it is to divide the load between them and have less heat, but this is an assumption.

[image: Non isolated half bridge supply]

Comment: \$Q_6\$ is just a cascode. It's nominally there to increase the effective VCEO of \$Q_7\$. Otherwise, just the one BJT's use is a bit too "marginal." It also distributes the dissipation. So I think there were two purposes here. Not just one. (It also may reduce the Early effect. But I don't think the designer cared about that, here.) If you need more details, I'll bother writing up my thoughts. Otherwise, no.

Comment: It is totally clear! In case we have only one transistor, what's it for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cascoded [transistors](https://www.onsemi.com/pdf/datasheet/mmbta42lt1-d.pdf) share the large applied voltage thus preventing either transistor exceeding its individual voltage rating (300 volts). You can put a few numbers onto the diagram to get a feel for how that voltage is shared if (say) the peak L-N voltage is 400 volts: -

[image]

> *There is a version with only one resistor and only one transistor.*

That's probably for a version where the L-N voltage that is lower than 300 volts.

> *I believe it is to divide the load between them and have less heat,
> but this is an assumption.*

It's certainly for voltage dividing (thus protecting the two transistors) but, without knowledge of the output current at node VCC12, it's hard to say but, quite likely also.

Comment: how is there "0 volts" behind the diode to N? Would it raise it a junction to make the output 12V?

Comment: 0 volts, is just a reference... it is not necessarily 0 volts regarding earth ground.

Comment: But why the transistor? Would it work without?

Comment: I don't have the full schematic so I can definitely say but, these days, it's likely there are other options.

Comment: The idea here is to supply 12V (~) to a mosfet driver. I don't have the schematic yet. There is a optocoupler that when ON will provide the mosfet gate with this 12V. I need a supply for the mosfets that are "isolated" between them(There is a diode in this 12V output for every driver.

Comment: Without a schematic it's not possible to say anything. Maybe when you do have a schematic you raise a new question on the specific subject.

Comment: I see, I'll work on that and post a new question. Thanks for your time!!